# Logging for network access

Tags: c#, .net, windows, service

I have request to create some kind of network loging for my program, and i don't have any clue how can i do this. I search on net but did not find nothing usefully and I'm not familiar with networking so i need to ask.

What exactly I need is next:
I have created silverlight application which are hosted on windows server 2008 R2. I developing windows service (will be installed on that server, service is created in C# with .net Framework 4.5) which have task to control access from network to one .xml config file. That file use Silverligh application.
So what I need is next information:
access (who open my silverlight page, from what address)
request (who want file, from what address)
response (file is sending to client or something like that, from what address)
acknowledge (file is successfully send to client)

Any suggestion or help is welcome.

Comment: What you want is enabling auditing for file/folder access. But the best place to ask is probably SuperUser, not StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Just host file on IIS (or serve with ASP.Net). Default IIS logging seem to be almost exact match to your requirements.

Comment: I have request to do this from my application. I know that IIS will have better logging then my application, but i must do this from my project. I can't change request.